# How to delete a file from a SFTP server programmatically using SharpSSH?

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, sharpssh

How to delete a file from a SFTP server using Tamir Gal's SharpSSH? I have been able to accomplish other functionality but deletion.

Comment: A long belated follow-up for this question. I added this in a few updates that I did at https://bitbucket.org/mattgwagner/sharpssh  to avoid re-compiling the library yourself.

Answer (score 24):

The SshExec class didn't work for me, but a little Reflection magic worked:

```
var prop = sftp.GetType().GetProperty("SftpChannel", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var methodInfo = prop.GetGetMethod(true);
var sftpChannel = methodInfo.Invoke(sftp, null);
((ChannelSftp) sftpChannel).rm(ftpPath);
```

Comment: Wow, what an ugly hack. Can't the so great sftp client delete files?

Comment: It's less ugly than recompiling you're own copy of the DLL.  The functionality is there ready to be used, it just wasn't exposed externally, so you're just poking into the object to call it.

Comment: This saved my time!

Answer (score 14):

To accomplish this you will need to modify the SharpSSH assembly to expose the functionality you require.

Obtain the source code and open $\SharpSSH-1.1.1.13.src\SharpSSH\Sftp.cs

Insert the following lines of code before the end of the class:

```
public void Delete(string path)
{
    SftpChannel.rm(path);
}
```

Recompile and reference the recompiled DLL in your project. You will now be able to delete files on the SFTP server.

Comment: Thank you!  Stumbled upon this and it works perfectly.  Just another quick tip for anyone who wants to compile this themselves, it's helpful to use the following post-build ILMerge command to end up with one handy assembly called SharpSSH.dll:  `ilmerge /target:library /out:"$(TargetDir)SharpSSH.dll" /v2 "$(TargetDir)Tamir.SharpSSH.dll" "$(TargetDir)DiffieHellman.dll" "$(TargetDir)Org.Mentalis.Security.dll"`

Answer (score 6):

Well you can also use **SshExec** class and then execute the "rm" command using "**RunCommand**" method. This way you wont have to recompile and build a new dll.

Answer (score 0):

Using Tamir's dll I would suggest to delete using the below code. In this way, you need not modify Tamir's dll, whereas the below code can be written in your class.

```
string fromFile = "/a/b/MyFile.txt"
SshExec se = new SshExec(host, username, password);
se.Connect(port);
se.RunCommand("rm " + fromFile);
```